# Force function to do nothing if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

The function below currently throws an error in the console because the variable is undefined if no query is appended to the URL. How can I make it do nothing in this case?

```
function getParamName(name, url) {
  return url ?? location.href.split(`?${name}=`)[1];
}
```

Comment: You might validate the ```location.href.split(`?${name}=`)``` if it returns array then get the index 1

Answer (score 1):

Use the `try-catch` block to ignore errors

```
try {
  Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
  Block of code to handle errors
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse the query string and use [`.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) to give you the value associated with a specific one. This will automatically handle the case where you have multiple query string parameters and if you try to get one that doesn't exist, it just returns `null`:

```js
function getParamName(name, url) {
  return url ?? new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1)).get(name);
}

console.log( getParamName("foo") );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do a null check on the function if the var is empty or not. So just check if the name is empty or not and run your code if not empty

Like this:

```
function getParamName(name, url) {
  if(name && url){
    return url ?? location.href.split(`?${name}=`)[1];
  }
}
```